# He came here on a fine morning/in a fine morning

Tags: prepositions

I know that the preposition 'on' and 'in'  are used in the following contexts

*1. He came in the morning.*

*2. He came here on Sunday morning.*

*3. He came here on 2nd october.*

*4. He came here on october 2nd, 2018.*

I know that in the sentence1 the preposition 'in' is used since morning is rather a long period.

In the sentences 2,3 and 4 'on' is used because it is followed by day or date. Even the third sentence refers to date though it is followed by the month December.

I would like to know why we say:

> *He came here on a fine morning*

and not:

> *He came here in a fine morning.*

Here *morning* does not refer to any day or date and refers to a period of time.

Is it because of the article *a* or something else?

It is not a duplicate of "in the morning vs on the morning".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking, the event happened "on" a calendar date or "in" a time period. I don't know if there's a formal grammar rule to that effect but that's how it works. You have correctly described standard usage (at least for US English).